# Почему в wordpress-е свойства bootstrap не работают как положено?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

Есть проект, написанный на wordpress. В нем вот такой вот код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="mainblogcontent">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 specializ">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1><?php echo get_cat_name( 5 );?></h1>
                    <ul><?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=5&pad_counts=0&hide_empty=0&title_li='); ?></ul>
                </div>     
        </div>     
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 spec_p">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="comands comands_desc">
                        <?php $category_description = category_description(); if (!empty($category_description)) echo '' . $category_description . ''; ?>

                    </div>
                    <div class="comandsf">

                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 comands_descf">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                    <div class="com-post">
                                        <?php if(get_locale() == 'ua_UA') { ?>
                                            <?php the_field('post'); ?>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <?php the_field('position'); ?>                 
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Он отображает по классам бутстрапа в col-md-4 по 3 фотографии в ряду, а в col-sm-6 и col-xs-6 должен по 2 фотографии....он отображает же...т.е. первые 6 картинок он отображает 2 и 1 в ряду, а остальные 6 картинок по 2 в ряду, как положено...Подскажите как это побороть?
П.С. в laravel данные классы bootstrap работают нормально (по 2 картинки в ряду, как сказано)

файл CSS:

```
.conteiner, mainblogcontent, .row { - не описаны в CSS-свойствах- }
.col-md-1, .col-xs-1, ... , .col-xs-12 {
position:relative;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.spec_p { padding-left: 30px; }
.specializ li { padding-bottom: 5px; }
.specializ h3 { font-family: "Roboto"; }
.comands, com-post { - прописаны цвета и пэддинги для разных тегов - }
.comands_desc  { height: 420px; }
```

Comment: WordPress использует темы, а в них свой css. Надо смотреть в инспекторе браузера, какие правила css имеют элементы. Ответить вот так, глядя на php-код без css, не представляется возможным.

Comment: сейчас добавлю CSS со свойствами классов, упомянутых в коде

Comment: ну да со стандартными, вроде, все ок - https://jsbin.com/fewehej/edit?html,output

Comment: KAGG Design , скинул ксс-свойства,  еще прикол... если поставить col-sm-4 и col-xs-4, то оно показываект по три и по одной картинке, в то время как col-md-4  показывает по ТРИ!!!в чем тут может быть подвох?